# Static HttpClient and CookieContainer

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, dotnet-httpclient

I created a base class ApiCaller for my application, which has a method to do some Setup on the client, and an abstract method CreateHttpClient() which is overridden in the child classes to return a static readonly property HttpClient called Instance. So each ChildApiCaller that inherits from ApiCaller gets it's own static HttpClient and it passes it's ChildUrl to the Setup on the base.

I come across some code I'd like to refactor into another Child ApiCaller and it contains this:

```
using(var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = container })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
```

So I don't see a way to swap the handler or container, except by creating another HttpClient. CookieContainer here can vary by each call through the containing method, therefore we get a new HttpClient with new cookies each time. Is there a way to use this variable CookieContainer with my pattern of using a static HttpClient per BaseAddress?